# eclipse: include abitrary files in jar export

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar, executable-jar

I have a directory of arbitrary files I want to include in my jar - however, I cannot figure out a way to do so that works with export -> "Runnable jar". I've tried the trick of making the directory a 'source path' but it is still absent when I build the jar. I realize I can manually add them into the jar (it is just a zip, after all) - or I could use an ant script or other build system - but I'm looking for something that works for an out-of-the-box Eclipse "Java project".

Here's an example. I want to try to load log4j.properties if it exists. If not, I want to write it out from an included 'default' in my jarfile. Finally, it loads the defaults if that fails.

Note that I have no idea yet if the code below works, it will likely need tweaking. I'm not asking for help with that, I'm just giving context for what I want to do.

```
        // initialize logging libraries
    File log4jFile = new File("log4j.properties");
    if (log4jFile.exists() & log4jFile.canRead()) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    else {
        try {
            InputStream log4jJarstream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(sepd + "resources" + sep + "log4j.properties");
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("log4j.properties"));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = log4jJarstream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            log4jJarstream.close();
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            BasicConfigurator.configure();
            log.warn("Error writing log4j.properties, falling back to defaults.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the code loading the file as a resource... which it seems Eclipse "saw" and as such was refusing to package the file. I put the file along side the class files and altered the way I search for the file, and it packaged it with the .class files and was able to be read during execution. New code snippet:

```
// initialize logging libraries
    File log4jFile = new File("log4j.properties");
    if (log4jFile.exists() & log4jFile.canRead()) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    }
    else {
        try {
            InputStream log4jJarstream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("log4j.properties"));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = log4jJarstream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            log4jJarstream.close();
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            BasicConfigurator.configure();
            log.warn("Error writing log4j.properties, falling back to defaults.");
            log.warn(e);
            log.warn("STACK TRACE:");
            int i = 0;
            StackTraceElement[] trace = e.getStackTrace();
            while (i < trace.length) {
                log.warn(trace[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the log4j.properties to my src folder, and exported the jar as a runnable. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try *Export --> JAR file* instead of exporting *Runnable JAR file*: it allows you to select multiple resources to include in the generated archive.

You can also specify the *Main-Class* property, just like with the latter option.

BTW it is more convenient if you use some kind of build tool (like [Ant `<jar>` target](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) or the [Maven Jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/)). If you use Eclipse to generate the JAR file, there is also an option to save an Ant buildfile that can do the task for you later on.

Comment: I already found the solution but cannot yet accept it. See my own answer to my question.